# Shorten string in R to inital of name first name.Lastname

Tags: r, string

I have a df with players names, formatted:

(Lastname, Firstname) ie: (Hill, Tyreek).

I need to get this to yield (first letter of first name. last name) ie: (T.Hill)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Just use the base string functions:

```r
output <- paste0(substr(df$Firstname, 1, 1), '.', df$Lastname)
```

Answer (score 1):

With grep/gsub . . .

```
n <- "Hill, Tyreek"

gsub("(\\w+), (\\w).+","\\2.\\1",n)
```